# C++ CreateProcess 'telnet' is not recognized

Tags: c++, winapi

When I pass the `ipconfig` command to the process, it stores the correct results in files.

```
char cmd[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c ipconfig";
SaveResult("ipconfig1.txt", NULL, cmd);

char appName[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
char cmd2[] = "/c ipconfig";
SaveResult("ipconfig2.txt", appName, cmd2);
```

But when i pass `wuauclt` or `telnet`

```
char cmd1[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c telnet";
SaveResult("telnet1.txt", NULL, cmd1);

char appName3[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
char cmd3[] = "/c telnet";
SaveResult("telnet2.txt", appName3, cmd3);

char cmd4[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c wuauclt";
SaveResult("wuauclt1.txt", NULL, cmd4);

char appName5[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
char cmd5[] = "/c wuauclt";
SaveResult("wuauclt2.txt", appName5, cmd5);
```

I get

> 'wuauclt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How to fix this problem and why it happens? Do it possible to launch through cmd.exe `telnet` or `wuauclt`?

Also on this PC `wuauclt` and `telnet` in common console opened from start working like expected.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
{
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

void SaveResult(const char *fileName, const char *appName, const char *commandLine)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    HANDLE h = CreateFile(convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(fileName),
        FILE_APPEND_DATA,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
        &sa,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    BOOL ret = FALSE;
    DWORD flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = NULL;
    si.hStdError = h;
    si.hStdOutput = h;

    ret = CreateProcess(appName==NULL ? NULL : convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(appName), commandLine == NULL ? NULL : convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(commandLine), NULL, NULL, TRUE, flags, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (ret)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char cmd[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c ipconfig";
    SaveResult("ipconfig1.txt", NULL, cmd);

    char appName[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    char cmd2[] = "/c ipconfig";
    SaveResult("ipconfig2.txt", appName, cmd2);

    char cmd1[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c telnet";
    SaveResult("telnet1.txt", NULL, cmd1);

    char appName3[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    char cmd3[] = "/c telnet";
    SaveResult("telnet2.txt", appName3, cmd3);

    char cmd4[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c wuauclt";
    SaveResult("wuauclt1.txt", NULL, cmd4);

    char appName5[] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    char cmd5[] = "/c wuauclt";
    SaveResult("wuauclt2.txt", appName5, cmd5);

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can you launch telnet, or wuauclt without the use of `CreateProcess`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, Yes it's working correct.

Comment: Try with the full path to the executable.

Comment: @drescherjm, sorry not clear what do you mean.

Comment: You gave the full path to cmd. try also with the full path to telnet.

Comment: A 32-bit process gets redirected to c:\windows\syswow64, afaik there is no 32-bit version of telnet.  You could use c:\windows\sysnative instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have not folder "c:\windows\sysnative", how it shoud work?

Comment: "sysnative" gets redirected to system32, the native OS directory.  Did you try it?

Comment: @HansPassant, tried "C:\\windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe", not working file is empty.

Comment: @drescherjm, tried 'char appName5[] = "c:\\windows\\system32\\telnet.exe";' also not working

Answer (score 2):

If you type in `ipconfig` in console window, the process will show IP information and exit.

On the other hand, if you type in `telnet` in console window, the process will show a prompt and waits for a response. The process does not finished automatically.

When you run this command with `CreateProcess`, `CreateProcess` will return immediately, but the process is not finished. Then you try to close the file handle which is still being used by `telnet`.

You can use `WaitForSingleObject` to wait until the process is complete. In the case of `telnet` the process doesn't complete. The example below demonstrates this problem.

For `CreateProcess`, supply the whole command line as the second parameter. Make sure the character buffer is writable, and freed at the end.

Side note, it is recommended to use wide character string for a Unicode program. It's fine to promote ANSI to UTF16, but not much is gained in this case. You can also use `CreateProcessA` along with `STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof(si) };` which accept ANSI character.

```
void SaveResult(const wchar_t *fileName, const wchar_t *commandLine)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    HANDLE h = CreateFile(fileName, FILE_WRITE_DATA, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
        &sa, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = NULL;
    si.hStdError = h;
    si.hStdOutput = h;

    wchar_t *writable_cmdline = _wcsdup(commandLine);
    BOOL success = CreateProcess(NULL, writable_cmdline,
        NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    bool finished = false;

    //wait for 1 second
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 100) <= 0)
        {
            finished = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(success)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    CloseHandle(h);
    free(writable_cmdline);

    if(!finished)
        printf("Process didn't finish\n");
}


int main()
{
    SaveResult(L"telnet.txt", L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c telnet");
    SaveResult(L"ipconfig.txt", L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c ipconfig");
    return 0;
}
```